# Is there any way to write concise code for below case

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an app which has two tabs. In the first `BookVC` tab, I use `UICollectionViewController` to show books and in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` i call a function that push the `BookDetailVC`.

And in Bookmark tab, i want to show all books which was bookmarked and when user select certain book, i want to push `BookDetailVC`. I know it can be achieved by writing the same code as in `BookVC`. But i don't want to repeat the same code.

I'd tried to make `BookmarkVC` subclass of `BookVC` and ended up as showing the same book in both `BookVC` and `BookmarkVC` since i'm using the same one instance of UICollectionView from `BookVC`. Is there any way to override `UICollectionView` of `BookVC` or any other approach to solve. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the wrong approach. The way you describe your bookmarks and your books View controller, it seems to me that they are identical, the only thing that changes is the content.

So, since collection views use data sources all you have to do is change the Data source based on whether you wanna show all books, or only the bookmarked ones.

---

Added code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"secondViewController") as! UIViewController
self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: yes they're identical. But i want to show them in separate vc. So i try to inherit bookmarkvc from bookvc and for datasource i filter object which is only bookmarked.

Comment: you don't have to subclass, it depends on how you are declaring your interface, for example, if you create a new storyboard with just this BooksVC, then you can instantiate it programatically and show it whenever you want, and inside the code use a flag or something to set the delegate.  see the attached code.

Comment: @noob it is not good to seperate vc for same data, i have posted solution creating model for book you can easily identify which Book is bookMarked

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing wrong use just need to reload collection view based on which button is clicked take boolean
**isBookMarkCliked:Bool**

For Better Readablity create Model For Book 
like

```
class Book {
    var title: String
    var author: String
    var isBookMarked:Bool 
    init(title: String, author: String, isBookMarked:Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
         self.isBookMarked = isBookMarked
    }
}
```

and declare two array globally with Book Model

```
arrForBooks:[Book] = []
arrForBookMarkedBooks:[Book] = []
```

Create CollectionViewDelegate methods using extension

```
extension YourClassVC: UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate
{

    //MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if isBookMarkClicked
        {
        return arrForBookMarkedBooks.count
        }
         return arrForBooks.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass
        var currentBook:Book = nil
        if isBookMarkClicked
            currentBook = arrForStoreDetails[indexPath.row]
        else
             currentBook = arrForBookMarkedBooks[indexPath.row]

        //Set data to cell from currentBook
        return cell

    }

    //MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        //Your code to push BookDetailVC
    }

}
```